# Add customer note from another script in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, methods, woocommerce, orders

I have a script that changes the status of orders based on our ERP system.

In addition to that, we need to add customer notes. I found the way to do it:

```php
$order->add_order_note($note);
$order->save();
```

Unfortunately this won't work outside the order edit screen, I tried to run it from my custom plugin. ([source](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/add-note-to-old-order/#post-11563061))

If I do it via `$order->update_status($status, $note);` it only updates the status.

Is there a way to add a note outside the edit screen? (Including e-mailing the customer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the note is for the customer (and has to be visible for him) you need to use instead the `WC_Order` method [`set_customer_note()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order.html#_set_customer_note) *(or both)*:

```
$order->set_customer_note($note);
// $order->add_order_note($note);
$order->save();
```

Or:

```
$order->set_customer_note($note);
$order->update_status($status, $note);
```

*This need to be done before **saving** the order data or **updating** the order status.*

---

To re-send the email notification to the customer (if needed) you can use from the current order ID:

```
$emails = WC()->mailer()->get_emails();

$emails['WC_Email_Customer_Completed_Order']->trigger( $order_id );
// OR: $emails['WC_Email_Customer_Processing_Order']->trigger( $order_id );
```

Comment: In case you don't want to override any actual customer note, do this to add a string to the existing data:
$order->set_customer_note($order->customer_message . ' ' . $your_message);'

Answer (score 0):

```
//Pass order id from hook or function with $order_id
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

$note = 'Add note here';
$order->add_order_note($note);
$order->save();
```

I'm constructing a new class of order. Passing the order ID and order note and then saving the order again.

This is how we update our site from our ERP. But as Loic said this method creates a private note. Use his

```
$order->set_customer_note($note);
```

to create a customer note.

Comment: I copied your code exactly and passed my order ID, still nothing happens. I think there's something wrong elsewhere interfering with woocommerce.

Comment: Are you sure you sure your plugin is running? As it sounds as though the code is note even being parsed?

Comment: It is, the status is beeing updated as well as everything else. It's the same function even.

Comment: Id be really interested in finding out the issue! Are there any console logs? Would you be happy to post your custom module code just so I can get an Idea of whats happening?

Comment: I found the issue! Loics answer was correct, but the message contained an umlaut (ü) wich wasn't handled correctly. It's fixed and working now! Thank you!